# ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment / form validation

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I am very new to html and javascript; I've only been coding a few weeks. I'm trying to create a registration form with validation and am having an issue with this assignment. I was getting the error in the title (left-hand side...) but now my validation function isn't working and I cannot see why.

This is my assignment:

> The following are your data validation rules:
>
> - Username/Password: Required and has to be at least 8 characters.
> - First Name/Last Name: Required.  No other requirements.
> - Email: Required.
> - Phone Number: Optional.  However, if user enters a phone number, you must check to make sure that it is in XXX-XXX-XXXX format, where X
>     are all numbers.
>
> When user clicks on the submit button, your validation logic will run
>   and display error messages on the screen if there are data issues. If
>   there are no data issues, you can just use “alert” to print a success
>   message. Include reset button to clear all form fields and errors.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Registration Form</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type="text/css" href = "regStyles.css"/>
    <script language="JavaScript">

        function validateForm()
        {
            var userName = document.getElementById('userName').value;
            var passWord = document.getElementById('passWord').value;
            var lastName = document.getElementById('lastName').value;
            var dateBirth = document.getElementById('dateBirth').value;
            var email = document.getElementById('email').value;

            if (userName == "" || passWord =="" || firstName == "" || lastName == "" || dateBirth == "" || email == "")
            {
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Only phone is optional, all other fields are required";
                return false;
            }
            else if (userName.length<8)
            {
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Username must be at least 8 characters.";
            }
            else if (passWord.length<8)
            {
                document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "Password must be at least 8 characters.";
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
<form name = "registration" id = "registration" action="submission.html" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();">
<h1>Registration</h1>
<span id="error" style="color:red;"></span>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Username:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="userName" placeholder="JaneDoe123"> (At least 8 characters)
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" id="passWord" placeholder="********"> (At least 8 characters)
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>First Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="Jane"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Last Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="lastName" placeholder="Doe"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Date of Birth:</td>
            <td><input type="date" name="dateBirth"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Email:</td>
            <td><input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" placeholder="jane.doe@email.com"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Phone Number:</td>
            <td><input type="tel" id="phoneNumber" name="phone" placeholder="502-555-1234"
                pattern="[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}"/>
                <span class="validity"></span> (optional)</td>
        </tr>
    </table>  
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"></button>
        <input type="reset">
</form>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `lastName = "" || dateBirth = ""` be `lastName == "" || dateBirth == ""`?

Comment: Ahh... Yes! Now i don't get the bug, but also don't seem to be getting my validation function to work.